# Lowering visible and actual amount of hearts player has

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If you've ever played Rocket Rumble on the Antvenom server, which is a great game, you'd notice that the player has, only **three** visible hearts, or to be technical, six. Here's a picture: 
 [image] Now, as you can see, the player has only three visible, or six actual hearts. What I'm interested in doing is lowering the health of a player to five visible hearts. Is this possible? Or is it just plugin trickery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "corrupt" potion effect. This may not work in later versions/snapshots due to bugs.

`/effect @p 21 (a number)`. The number is at or greater then 127. Each integer greater then 127 deducts 4 hearts (8 health points). If the number is less then 127, it will add hearts, starting at 1 being 4 hearts, then add 4 per level. 126 would add a really big amount of hearts so don't screw up!

Comment: Which snapshots will this **not** work in?

Comment: Some older ones in between 1.6 and 1.7. I think it works with 1.7.5 but not 100% sure. The latest snapshots (1.8 ones) are usually filled with bugs, so it might not work. The best way to find out is to test it on every version you are using/supporting.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect give @p health_boost (a number)`